# Can't import extension function in Android App Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, extension-function

Running into an Issue early on in importing a declared extension function in another Kotlin File (Extensions.kt), call the extension function From another class (ForecastsRepository.kt) it doesn't compile but when i remove it there is no problem with the build. Obviously I need it and wonder why importing it would become an issue .

Here is the class:

```
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.base.Success
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.custom.errors.ErrorHandler
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.custom.errors.NoDataException
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.custom.errors.NoResponseException
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.entitymappers.forecasts.ForecastMapper
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.features.home.di.HomeScope
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.network.api.OpenWeatherApi
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.network.response.ErrorResponse
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.room.dao.forecasts.ForecastDao
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.room.dao.utils.StringKeyValueDao
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.room.models.forecasts.DbForecast
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.utils.Utils
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.catch
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import javax.inject.Inject
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.extensions.applyCommonSideEffects//import


@HomeScope
class ForecastsRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val openWeatherApi: OpenWeatherApi,
    private val forecastDao: ForecastDao,
    private val stringKeyValueDao: StringKeyValueDao
) {

    private val forecastCacheThresholdMillis = 3 * 3600000L //3 hours//

    fun getForecasts(cityId: Int) = flow {
        stringKeyValueDao.get(Utils.LAST_FORECASTS_API_CALL_TIMESTAMP)
            ?.takeIf { !Utils.shouldCallApi(it.value, forecastCacheThresholdMillis) }
            ?.let { emit(getDataOrError(NoDataException())) }
            ?: emit((getForecastFromAPI(cityId)))
    }
        //.applyCommonSideEffects()
        .catch {
            emit(getDataOrError(it))
        }

    private suspend fun getForecastFromAPI(cityId: Int) = openWeatherApi.getWeatherForecast(cityId)
        .run {
            if (isSuccessful && body() != null) {
                stringKeyValueDao.insert(
                    Utils.getCurrentTimeKeyValuePair(Utils.LAST_FORECASTS_API_CALL_TIMESTAMP)
                )
                forecastDao.deleteAllAndInsert(ForecastMapper(body()!!).map())
                getDataOrError(NoDataException())
            } else {
                Error(
                    NoResponseException(
                        ErrorHandler.parseError<ErrorResponse>(errorBody())?.message
                    )
                )
            }
        }

    private suspend fun getDataOrError(throwable: Throwable) =
        forecastDao.get()
            ?.let { dbValue -> Success(getForecastList(dbValue)) }
            ?: Error(throwable)

    private suspend fun getForecastList(dbForecast: DbForecast) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        dbForecast.list.map { it.forecast }
    }
}
```

and here is the file for the Extension functions:

```
package com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.extensions

import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.base.Progress
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.base.Result
import com.benmohammad.climatemvvm.utils.Utils
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.onCompletion
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.onStart
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.retryWhen
import okhttp3.Call
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import java.io.IOException




fun String.capitalizeWords(): String = this.split(' ').joinToString(" "){it.capitalize()}

@PublishedApi
internal inline fun Retrofit.Builder.callFactory(crossinline body: (Request) -> Call) =
    callFactory(object: Call.Factory {
        override fun newCall(request: Request): Call = body(request)
    })

@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline fun Retrofit.Builder.delegatingCallFactory(delegate: dagger.Lazy<OkHttpClient>): Retrofit.Builder =
    callFactory {
        delegate.get().newCall(it) }

fun < T: Any> Flow<Result<T>>.applyCommonSideEffects() =  //<<-----------T H I S Function!!!!HERE
    retryWhen {  cause, attempt ->
        when {
            (cause is IOException && attempt < Utils.MAX_RETRIES) -> {
                delay(Utils.getBackOffDelay(attempt))
                true
            }
            else -> {
                false
            }
        }
    }
        .onStart { emit(Progress(isLoading = true)) }
        .onCompletion { emit(Progress(isLoading = false)) }




    fun Job?.cancelIfActive() {
        if(this?.isActive == true) {
        cancel()
    }
}
```

as it doesnt compile it leads me to think the bug is deeper.

the IDE also hunderlines the function call stating it is "Unresolved reference"

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/BenMohammad/ClimateMVVM)

Thanks any advice appreciated.